# Send and retrive data from database and display in select box without refreshing page in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

**The PLAN**

I am working in CodeIgniter; on Click Add button, a modal will pop Out and user will add new Item (Item ID, Item Desc, Rate and UoM) and then press submit button.

I send the data to database using AJAX without refreshing page and its working properly.

**The PROBLEM**

Now I want to retrieve data from database and append in SELECT BOX of item-ID and ITEM Desc respectively. I have done writing the code of MODEL and CONTROLLER in CodeIgniter, and now need AJAX code to append my fetched data at end of my pre-populated select boxes (on first time page load, select boxes get populated through php dynamically).

I want all work done without refreshing page.

Any kind of help or suggestion?

**CODE OF MODEL in CODEIGNITER**

```
<?php
  class PostModel extends CI_Model {

  function getLastRecord(){
  $query = "select * from sale order by itemid DESC limit 1";
  $res = $this->db->query($query);

  if($res->num_rows() > 0) {
    return $res->result();
  }
  return result();
  }
  }
  ?>
```

**CODE OF CONTROLLER**

```
public function index()
{
    $data['last'] = $this->PostModel->getLastRecord();
    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view('salevocher', $data);
    $this->load->view('footer');
}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to insert the newly created item into `<select>`. In that case your ajax that sends create new item should receive back the new id and then you have what you need to be able to update the select. Using json could return the whole new item...then simpy add new `<option>` with new data and sort the options if needed

Comment: @charlietfl , you are right the same as you said , how can i receive it back ,so i will be able to append it in my select box ? Thanks

Comment: codigniter db-> insert should return the new id. So then you have the whole new object in your post data and can add the id property to it and `echo  json_encode($newitem)`. In ajax success create a new `<option>` using response data

Comment: @charlietfl can you please tell me complete ajax code for it...Please Please Please. it may help me out.

Comment: It's not complicated for the ajax. `$.post(createItemUrl, newitem, function(response){ var opt ='<option value="' + response.id +'">' +response.description +'</option>'; $(select).append(opt);},'json')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ajax should populate your selectbox after the success response:

```
$.ajax({
    url: ...,
    success: function(data) {
        loadMySelectbox();
    }
});

function loadMySelectbox() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'controller/getSelectboxData',
        success: function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                $('#mySelectbox').append($('<option>').text(value.item_desc).attr('value', value.item_id));
            });
        }
    });
}
```

**PHP**

```
//model
function getLastRecord(){
    //select only data you really need
    $query = "select itemid, itemdesc from sale order by itemid DESC limit 1";

//controller
public function getSelectboxData() {
    $data = $this->PostModel->getLastRecord();
    $this->output->set_content_type('application/json')
         ->set_output(json_encode($data));
}
```

Comment: wouldn't use index as option value...it has no relationship to db fields

Comment: @FelippeDuarte , which url to be placs in loadMySelectbox function's URL attribute??  the url of VIEW where my select boxes are???

Comment: The url you select all data that you wish to use in your select box. Probably you need to create another controller method to get this data. I'll edit the answer

Comment: @FelippeDuarte , i have tried your ajax function... and i got a lil issue here... i have typed the following code ...

function loadMySelectbox() {
    $.ajax({
        url: baseurl + 'index.php/Welcome/getSelectboxData',
        success: function(data) {
         //alert('running');
            $.each(data, function(index, value) {
             alert(value + ' ' + index);
                $('#opt1').append($('<option>').text(value.itemid).attr('value', value.itemid));

            });
        } 
   });
}

Comment: @FelippeDuarte , when i call alert function in $.each of function as alert(value + ' ' + index);  it  alert as [object Object] 0 .
and aslo the itemid and item desc id not appending in respective selectt boxes... please help me in this ...

Comment: It's not value, index. It's key, value, and your value is your object. Take a look at my answer again. Your value is your object, so you can get your values using `value.item_id` or `value.item_desc`, or whatever data you have in return.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte you rocks. Fantastic. I got what i want. Thanks

Comment: @Felippe Duarte 

when $('#mySelectbox').append($('<option>').text(value.item_desc).attr('value', value.item_id));

here not get any data . then how to show  alert('Could not found data' );  ?

Comment: @ShivendraKr.Sahu I guess you can do with `if(data.length==0){alert('Could not found data' ); } else { $.each...}`